# Users submitted data is not loading into my database

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a small website where people can upload a photo and some text into a database. The code I have written is this

```
<?php
  $msg = "";

  if (isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $target = "../images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


    $db = mysqli_connect('xxxxx','xxxxxx''xxxxx''xxxx');


    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, description) VALUES ('$image', '$description')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      $msg = "Posted successfully";
    } else {
      $msg = "Post failed";
    }

  }

?>
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <title>Upload</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/upload.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="size" value="100000000">
      <div>
        <input type="file" name="image">
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Say somthing about this product...."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The images are loading into the folder "images" on the server but the files don't appear on the database. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I know you are pretty open to SQL-Injection...

Comment: well, firstly: you don't escape your data or use parameterized statements, leaving your code wide open for SQL-injections. just imagine someone posting the description `'); DROP TABLE images; -- ` secondly: you just assume success without checking for any errors. have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: To check if a submission is present.. it's better practice to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` Additionally, can you please tell us what you have tried? and what do you mean by "files don't appear on the database"? you mean the filename, right? and not the file itself??

Comment: @Yes, sorry. The filename is not appearing.

Comment: try echoing your sql query and running it on the server to see what error(s) you get. could be that your description has an apostrophe in it. You should clean your input to avoid SQL injection as mentioned by others, and probably escape it too, to allow for special characters.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: by the way: SQL-injection is the least of your troubles. you do not in any way validate the file that's being uploaded. any attacker uploading a php-file and then accessing it via browser could **compromise your whole server**, not just the database.

Comment: As @FranzGleichmann said, you have opened the door to Little Johnny tables - https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Get into the habit of checking the return value when you execute SQL commands. Also, you could try manully executing the command in the MySQl command line console and see what error message it gives you

Comment: @Mawg please read your comment and the post you linked to. read it carefully: mysql != mysql**i**